# Presto on Amazon S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, presto

I'm trying to use Presto on Amazon S3 bucket, but haven't found much related information on the Internet.

I've installed Presto on a micro instance but I'm not able to figure out how I could connect to S3. There is a bucket and there are files in it. I have a running hive metastore server and I have configured it in presto hive.properties. But when I try to run the LOCATION command in hive, its not working.

IT throws an error saying cannot find the file scheme type s3.

And also I do not know why we need to run hadoop but without hadoop the hive doesnt run. Is there any explanation to this.

[This](https://blog.mustardgrain.com/2010/09/30/using-hive-with-existing-files-on-s3/) and [this](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/connector/hive.html) are the documentations i've followed while set up.

Comment: A bit away from you question, but why are you not using aws EMR? all these configurations are there out of the box and as far as I know presto, it needs a cluster to perform well, a single ec2 instance is not enough.

One more note: if you don't want to launch a cluster to run presto, you can use aws Athena, which is a service provided by amazon that provides Presto as a service.

Athena pricing is per data scanned, so if your data is small then you are off cost, they charge you 5$ per 1 TB scanned. I strongly suggest it if you are just experimenting Presto

Answer (score 7):

Presto uses the Hive metastore to map database tables to their underlying files. These files can exist on S3, and can be stored in a number of formats - CSV, ORC, Parquet, Seq etc.

The Hive metastore is usually populated through HQL (Hive Query Language) by issuing DDL statements like `CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE ...` with a `LOCATION ...` clause referencing the underlying files that hold the data.

In order to get Presto to connect to a Hive metastore you will need to edit the hive.properties file (EMR puts this in `/etc/presto/conf.dist/catalog/`) and set the `hive.metastore.uri` parameter to the thrift service of an appropriate Hive metastore service.

The Amazon EMR cluster instances will automatically configure this for you if you select Hive and Presto, so it's a good place to start.

If you want to test this on a standalone ec2 instance then I'd suggest that you first focus on getting a functional hive service working with the Hadoop infrastructure. You should be able to define tables that reside locally on the hdfs file system. Presto complements hive, but does require a functioning hive set-up, presto's native ddl statements are not as feature complete as hive, so you'll do most table creation from hive directly.

Alternatively, you can define Presto connectors for a mysql or postgresql database, but it's just a jdbc pass through do I don't think you'll gain much.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I want to try presto with absolutely no cost associated. Please check the edits , I had more doubts after going through the relevant material you just mentioned.

Comment: With Amazon EMR I would incur costs so i'm trying to avoid that. Is there any way around for this.

Comment: I wrote the following [post](http://blog.danielcorin.com/code/2016/04/11/querying-s3-with-presto.html) last year on the topic. I haven't tried the setup since but there a chance it could help. The general idea is to use a Docker container as the Hive metastore so you don't need a managed service like EMR just for the purposes of routing your Presto queries.

Comment: @Euan is any of that information (like how EMR puts config in a special folder that you can't find in presto docs) available anywhere, or is it all tribal knowledge at this point? Trying to get a basic Presto -> Hive -> S3 setup working and it's surprisingly awful.